# jQuery - progressivly showing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to show some divs, one by one, with a sliding effect from the left or right part of the screen. So far i'm stuck between [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nc6cwtqm/)

```
<button id='animer'>animer</button>
<div class="left">from left</div>
<div class="right">from right</div>
<div class="left">from left</div>
<div class="right">from right</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.left, .right').hide();
    $('#animer').click(function() {
        $(".left").toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);
        $(".right").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
    });
 });
</script>
```

and [that](https://jsfiddle.net/92yxc49u/)

```
<button id='animer'>animer</button>
<div class="all">from left</div>
<div class="all">from right</div>
<div class="all">from left</div>
<div class="all">from right</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.all').hide();
    $('#animer').click(function() {
      $('.all').first().show('slow', function showNextOne() {
        $(this).next('.all').show('slow', showNextOne);
      });    
    });
  });
</script>
```

But i need this to work no matter the divs order, because the "left" or "right" items will come randomly.

Help will be much appreciated as i am not as competent as i wished in jQuery. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index from `each()` loop for delay and set direction based on condition if current div `hasClass()` left or not.

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').hide();
  $('#animer').click(function() {
    $('div').each(function(i) {
      let dir = $(this).hasClass('left') ? 'left' : 'right';
      $(this).delay(i * 1000).toggle('slide', {direction: dir})
    })
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>
<button id='animer'>animer</button>
<div class="left">from left</div>
<div class="right">from right</div>
<div class="left">from left</div>
<div class="right">from right</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The following uses the `all` variable to keep a list of all of the divs. When the button is clicked, the `slideNext()` function is executed, checking the class of the current item to decide on toggle direction, and specifying `slideNext` (itself) as the function to run when the toggle is complete.

```js
$(function() {
  var all = $('.left, .right').hide();
  $('#animer').click(function() {
    var i = 0;
    (function slideNext() {
      if (i < all.length) {
        var current = all.eq(i);
        current.toggle("slide", {
          direction: current.hasClass("left") ? "left" : "right"
        }, 500, slideNext);
      }
      i++;
    })();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button id='animer'>animer</button>
<div class="left">from left</div>
<div class="right">from right</div>
<div class="left">from left</div>
<div class="right">from right</div>
```